# Remove noise on edge (compression deffects)

Tags: image-processing, filters, noise, reconstruction

I have the images of cartoons, that were compressed. The example:

[image: Original image]

They have such noise, that is not easy to delete.

[image]

Even though the pixels are on the gray background, the noise pixels can be of very different colors and if I look at the histogram (of grayscale image) of such image I see a lot of bins around the bin of main color. But I can't just delete the colors of value, that are not of main color, because there is a risk to delete some important features (as eye, for example). Also I've tried to posterize image (example presents 8 colors), but some pixels still remain.

[image]

Also I've tried median filter, but it is not able to vanish such heavy noise ( I use 3*3 filter).

Please, give some methods that can effectively remove the noise in this case. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: There are numerous papers specifically on denoising cartoons. There are also practical guides on sites like [doom9](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=165295) that cover the practical aspects.

Answer (score 1):

The Total Variation (TV, a.k.a. Rudin-Osher-Fatemi functional) denoising wold help here.
You can apply it on every color layer or look for a vectorized version if th eresults ar enot good enough for you.

Good references of tsable and easy to implememnt algorithms for TV denoising are for example:

- [Chambolle's algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.5226)
- the Chambolle-Pock [primal dual algorithm](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/publications/a-first-order-primal-dual-algorithm-for-convex-problems-with-applications-to-imaging)

Both references have good performance and are easy to implement from the papers.